# Laravel - How to combine sortBy and groupBy in Laravel collection

Tags: laravel

I am consuming external API in Laravel-5.8 using Guzzle:

```
public  function index()
{
    try{
    $client = new Client();
    $res = $client->request('GET','https://example.com/tracking/JKK998', [
       'query' => ['key' => 'jkkkm7725']
   ])->getBody();
    $geoLocation = json_decode($res->getContents(), true);
    $currentLocationGroup = collect($geoLocation)->groupBy(function ($data) {
        return Carbon::parse($data['current_timestamp'])->format('d-m-Y');
    })->all();        
    return view('index', [
        'currentLocationGroup' => $currentLocationGroup,
        'geoLocation' => $geoLocation
    ]);
    }catch (Exception $exception) {
        Log::error($exception);
        return back();
    }
}
```

How do I combine sortBy() and groupBy() in $currentLocationGroup for current_timestamp?

Thanks

Comment: change date format to `..->format('Y-m-d')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
        $currentLocationGroup = collect($geoLocation)
            ->groupBy('current_timestamp')
            ->sortByDesc('current_timestamp'); // or sortBy()
```

There is no need to format timestamp to `d-m-Y`.